# Limit number of ipython or jupyter threads

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I run `jupyter` (notebook or qtconsole versions) or `ipython`, I can see that anywhere between 4-22 threads are used (seen on `top`). This is just on startup before even doing anything. **How do I limit the number of threads used?**

I have tried setting:

```
export MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

but this only limits the number of threads used by `numpy`, and this seems to be a separate issue.